# Adding a csv attachment to slack webhook in python

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to use a Slack webhook to notify a channel about a csv file for that day as well as post a link to it to attach. https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments doesn't use any examples of actual attachments and only includes links. I'm wondering if its even possible to send a csv file that my code is generating and attaching it from its path via `os.path.basename(csvfile)`

I'm trying use the format thats demonstrated here: https://gist.github.com/devStepsize/b1b795309a217d24566dcc0ad136f784 but am not sure if this allows for actual file attachments. So, I'd appreciate any help/direction in this matter. Is it even possible to send file attachments via a Slack webhook and if so, how should one go about doing so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to post files to Slack using the incoming Webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742775/is-it-possible-to-post-files-to-slack-using-the-incoming-webhook)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not attach a file via webhook. You can only include media links for specific formats that will then automatically be unfurled, e.g. images or videos.

To send a file into a channel you need to upload and share it in the channel via Slack API. The API method [`files.upload`](http://files.upload) has that exact purpose. Make sure to include the channel ID in the `channels` property to enable the optional sharing function.

Note that for using the [Slack Web API](https://api.slack.com/web) you will need a token.