# Upload a file to slack with files.upload in PHP

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to use the files.upload method to upload a file to Slack, but I only got a blank message so far.

This is the code, I found this script on the internet, but it's not working.

```
<?php
include '../connessione.php';

$slacktoken = "myToken"; //this is not the real token ofc
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$file = new CurlFile('../tmp/slack_icon.png', 'image/png');

$postitems =  array(
    'token' => $slacktoken,
    'channels' => "test_channel",
    'file' =>  $file,
    'text' => "This is my photo",
    'title' => "Photo title",
    'filename' => "myIcon.jpg"
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://slack.com/api/files.upload");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postitems);

//Execute curl and store in variable
$data = curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Edit: after lots of tests I got this message if I echo the $data variable:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"missing_scope","needed":"files:write:user","provided":"identify,commands"}
```

**UPDATE**
I'll post here the full working code.

```
<?php
include '../connessione.php';

    // Buffer all upcoming output...
    ob_start();

    // Send your response.
    echo "Here be response";

    // Get the size of the output.
    $size = ob_get_length();

    // Disable compression (in case content length is compressed).
    header("Content-Encoding: none");

    // Set the content length of the response.
    header("Content-Length: {$size}");

    // Close the connection.
    header("Connection: close");

    // Flush all output.
    ob_end_flush();
    ob_flush();
    flush();

    // Close current session (if it exists).
    if(session_id()) session_write_close();


$channel = $_POST['channel_id'];
$slacktoken = "myToken";
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
$file = new CurlFile('slack_icon.png', 'image/png');



$postitems =  array(
        'token' => $slacktoken,
        'channels' => "test_channel",
        'file' =>  $file,
        'text' => "This is my photo",
        'title' => "Photo title",
        'filename' => "myIcon.jpg"
    );

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://slack.com/api/files.upload");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postitems);

//Execute curl and store in variable
$data = curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

The initial part is taken from this [continue processing php after sending http response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738208/10171297). That's needed to send an immediate answer back to Slack and avoid the "Timeout was reached" message.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunatly we won’t be able to help you without an error message. If you’re getting a blank screen, trying removing the `?>` from the end of your page and trying again. Make sure you have [error reporting turned on](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Otherwise we have no idea what the problem might be. Good luck!

Comment: @ThomasEdwards Hello! I have the error reporting turned on, but I'm still getting a blank screen if I go to the webpage. I also tried to remove the `?>`, but nothing.

Comment: If I run the script through the slash command I get a blank message from my slack app

Comment: Obviously your token does not have the required scopes: you need to add `files:write:user` scope to your token

Comment: @ErikKalkoken How do i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Missing scopes**

You token is missing the necessary scopes, here: `files:write:user`.

To add additional scopes:

Assuming you have a Slack app, go to the management page for your app and then add it on the "Ouath" sub page there is a scope section where you can add it. here is a direct link to your apps: [https://api.slack.com/apps](http://api.slack.com/apps).

After that you need to re-install your app to the workspace, so the changes become active.

**Working with CurlFile**

Another potential pitfall is that `CurlFile` apparently only works with absolute paths to your file. ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28676891/4379151)). A quick fix would be something like this:

`$file = new CurlFile(realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../tmp/slack_icon.png'), 'image/png');`

Comment: I created a bot user and now I have another OAuth token. Using this new token now I get this `{"ok":false,"error":"no_file_data"}`

Comment: Alright, now I get this `{"ok":true,"file":{"id":"FDZF1LH0R","created":1541785891,"timestamp":1541785891,"name":"myIcon.jpg".....` I cut all the string cause it's too long, but it seems like it's working, but if I run it through slack slash command I get a Timeout

Comment: Cool. Then I would say the initial question has been answered. How to work with the 3 second timeout on slash commands it a whole other topic. and already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36195924/slack-php-api-avoid-timeout-error/42272824#42272824

Comment: I tried to add `ignore_user_abort(true);
ob_start();
echo('{"response_type": "in_channel", "text": "Checking, please wait..."}');
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header('Content-Length: '.ob_get_length());
ob_end_flush();
ob_flush();
flush();`
But it still gives me a timeout error. However the uploads works and the file shows on the slack anyway. So not it's just a matter of details

Comment: I never got it to work with the buffer capture approach (ob_start(), ..) either. But check the question I linked for the curl based approach. That one works great.

Comment: Will try that. Thank you!