# Laravel Slack notification attachment

Tags: laravel, slack

I am sending an attachment in laravel slack notification. Attachment is sent as a link. I want to download the file sent as an attachment, there is no option for download.

[image]

Comment: Can you post you current notification code?

Comment: $url = url(storage_path('\app\error_log\test.txt'));
        return (new SlackMessage)
                ->from('Import Application Batch', ':application batch:')
                ->to($this->slackChannelName)
                ->content($this->batchNotification)
                ->attachment(function ($attachment) use ($url) {
                    $attachment->title('Application Batch Error Log', $url);
                });

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to post files to Slack using the incoming Webhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742775/is-it-possible-to-post-files-to-slack-using-the-incoming-webhook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to upload a file through slack incoming webhook. You can check more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36287627/5152147